# SweetAlert implementation in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5, sweetalert

I'm trying to make a delete alert in my Laravel application but the problem is when I click on delete button, the alert comes but without confirming the alert button, the delete form gets submitted and the item gets removed from the database.

```
        @foreach($album_names as $album)
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $album->album_name }}</td>
          <td>
             {!! Form::open(['url' => "album/{$album->id}", 'method' => 'delete','id'=>'delete_form']) !!}
            <button class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">Delete</button>
              {!! Form::close() !!}
           </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('button#delete').on('click', function(){
            swal({
              title             : "Are you sure?",
              text              : "You will not be able to recover this Album!",
              type              : "warning",
              showCancelButton  : true,
              confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
              confirmButtonText : "Yes, delete it!",
              cancelBUttonText  : "No, Cancel delete!",
              closeOnConfirm    : false,
              closeOnCancel     : false
            },
      function(isConfirm){
        if(isConfirm){
          swal("Deleted!","your album has been deleted", "success");
          $("#delete_form").submit();
        }
        else{
          swal("cancelled","Your album is safe", "error");
        }
      }
);});
</script>
```

Comment: Try `$('button#delete').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault();....`

Comment: can you please elaborate ? im new into js though :3 @RayonDabre

Comment: Did that work ? I am not sure about the fix..But was a guess...You need to prevent the default behavior of the button or else it will submit the form...

Comment: thanks a lot it worked :D

Comment: Glad it helped.. _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the type of the button because the default option is to submit your form. No js needed to fix this problem. Simply do this:

```
<button type="button">I don't submit anything</button>

<button type="submit">I do submit</button>
```